# Add component v-on events (@mousenter) within a mixin

Tags: vue.js

I want to make a Vue Mixin that applies similar hover events and classes.

Right now I add this to each component, but would prefer to make this into a mixin.

Is this possible, or is there an easier way to accomplish this without having to include `@mouseenter` and `@mouseleave`?

```
<div 
  @mousenter="hovering=true" 
  @mouseleave="hovering=false"
  :class="[hovering ? 'elevation-4' : 'elevation-2']">`
```

---

I'd prefer to import something like:

```
export default {
    data: () => ({ hovering: false }),
    mounted(){
        // something here to use mouseenter/mouseleave
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```js
Vue.config.devtools = false
Vue.config.productionTip = false

const myMixin = {
  data: () => ({ hovering: false }),
}

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mixins: [myMixin]
})
```

```css
section {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
.elevation-4 {
  background-color: red
}
.elevation-2 {
  background-color: green
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <section 
    @mouseenter="hovering=true" 
    @mouseleave="hovering=false"
    :class="[hovering ? 'elevation-4' : 'elevation-2']">
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `mixin` like so:

**lib/mixins/hover.js**

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return { isHovering: false };
  },
  computed: {
    klass() {
      return this.isHovering ? 'o-hoverable--on' : 'o-hoverable--off';
    },
  },
  methods: {
    onEnter() {
      this.isHovering = true;
    },
    onLeave() {
      this.isHovering = false;
    },
  },
};
```

And then use it like this:

**index.vue**

```
<template>
  <div :class="klass" @mouseenter="onEnter" @mouseleave="onLeave">hover me</div>
</template>

<script>
import hover from '~/lib/mixins/hover';

export default {
  mixins: [hover],
};
</script>
```

Note that you'll still need to manually bind the events and the class, but you'll get to reuse the definitions of both.